How to dispatch async actions from one slice based on events in other Redux slices?
Using the createAsyncThunk + createSlice APIs within Redux, I'm writing an ErrorSlice for my app that is meant to listen to rejected thunks elsewhere in the app and add the error to a shared error state.
NB: (The reason I am not setting errors at the slice level is that many of my app components need to fetch data across multiple collections, and handling the errors across multiple slices is more complexity than is needed).
There is one scenario that is causing me problems, however. If any API call across any slice receives a 401 NOT AUTHORIZED, we need to dispatch the logout thunk, which clears local state, and set the user in state to the default user/initialState.
In the old Redux system, this is how we handled it (Redux actions extracted here, reducers omitted because they are basically boilerplate):
export function handleError(dispatch, err, type) {
  console.error('Invoking the error handler with the following error:', err);
  if (err.error && err.error.message) {
    switch (err.error.message) {
      case 'Not Authorized':
        dispatch(logout());
        break;
      default:
        dispatch(addError({ message: err.error.message, type: type }));
    }
    return;
  }
}

export function logout() {
  return dispatch => {
    return apiCall('delete', `/users/logout`)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.clear();
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(DEFAULT_STATE_CURRENT_USER.user));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        handleError(dispatch, err, 'user');
        throw err;
      });
  };
}

Now here's the new ErrorSlice:
const errorSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'errors',
  initialState,
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          authUser.rejected,
          updatePassword.rejected,
          getUser.rejected,
          updateUser.rejected,
          forgotPassword.rejected,
          verifyEmail.rejected,
          resendVerificationEmail.rejected,
        ),
        (state, action) => {
          state.push({type: 'user', error: action.payload})
        },
      ).addMatcher(
        isAnyOf(
          authUser.fulfilled,
          updatePassword.fulfilled,
          getUser.fulfilled,
          updateUser.fulfilled,
          forgotPassword.fulfilled,
          verifyEmail.fulfilled,
          resendVerificationEmail.fulfilled,
        ),
        (state, action) => {
          return state.filter(error => error?.type !== 'user');
        },
      )

The problem is since you can't dispatch thunks from reducers, and you can't listen to actions dispatched in other slices from a thunk, I don't see a way to catch this Not Authorized scenario and dispatch the appropriate actions.

Your best bet may be to create a custom listener middleware that can listen for these specific rejected actions and dispatch the logout action.
See

createListenerMiddleware
startListening
Listener API

Basic Example:
logoutListener
import { createListenerMiddleware, isAnyOf } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// action imports

const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: isAnyOf(
    authUser.rejected,
    forgotPassword.rejected,
    getUser.rejected,
    resendVerificationEmail.rejected,
    updatePassword.rejected,
    updateUser.rejected,
    verifyEmail.rejected,
  ),
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    listenerApi.dispatch(logout());
  },
});

export default listenerMiddleware;

Add the middleware to your store when it's configured,
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// import reducers
import logoutListener from '../path/to/logoutListener';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()
      .concat(logoutListener.middleware),
});

An alternative could also be to continue using that handleError utility in each thunk that is capable of dispatching the logout action.
Example:
export function handleError(err, type, thunkApi) {
  console.error('Invoking the error handler with the following error:', err);

  if (err.error?.message) {
    switch (err.error.message) {
      case 'Not Authorized':
        thunkApi.dispatch(logout());
        break;

      default:
        thunkApi.dispatch(addError({
          message: err.error.message,
          type
        }));
    }
  }
}

const authUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "authUser",
  async (arg, thunkApi) => {
    ...

    try {
    } catch(error) {
      handleError(error, "user", thunkApi);
      thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  },
);

